# Counting when one date is less than another date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula, countif

Within Google Sheets I would like to count the number of date values when the date in column B (Actual) is less than the date in column A (Expected)

I would like to have the total number of dates when Expected>Actual in a single cell.
I believe the formula in Google Sheets would look something like this, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet1'!A1:A500,">"&'Sheet1'!B1:B500)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make a note that dates are actually numbers.
So a date like `September/23/2020` is the same as `44086`

In addition to Marios correct answer, you can also use a query formula

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:B,"select count(B) where A>B")
```

[image]

If you just want the result omitting the header, you can use

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:B,"select count(B) where A>B label count(B) '' ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are comparing date objects and not texts that look like dates. To check whether a value is a date or not, do that:

```
=isdate(A1) //  returns true if the value in A1 is an actual date
```

Generally, you could convert the text to date:

Try `to_date` :

```
=COUNTIF(arrayformula(to_date(Sheet1!A1:A500)),">"&to_date(Sheet1!B1:B500))
```

[image: example]

or `datevalue`:

```
=COUNTIF(arrayformula(DATEVALUE(Sheet1!A1:A500)),">"&DATEVALUE(Sheet1!B1:B500))
```